# Webservice authentication using Digital certificate , Server Jboss Soa 5.3.1

Tags: web-services, soa, jboss5.x, digital-certificate

I am using Jboss SOA 5.3.1 as application server. Please guide me what are the steps should be followed at server side and client side.